# Finding the corresponding S3 generic method of `plot` in R, and the package that contains this method

Tags: r, plot

Here is a piece of sample code from R package CatDyn:

```
require(CatDyn)

lgahi <- as.CatDynData(x=lolgahi,
step="day",
fleet.name="Fk",
coleff=2,
colcat=1,
colmbw=3,
unitseff="nboats",
unitscat="kg",
unitsmbw="kg",
nmult="bill",
season.dates=c(as.Date("1990-01-31"),as.Date("1990-05-30")))

plot(lgahi,mark=TRUE,offset=c(NA,NA,.75),hem="S")
```

As `plot` is an S3 generic here, how could I find which generic method is being called (especially in the case where the object being plotted have multiple class names), and how could I find the package that contains this generic method?

Comment: `class(lgahi)` will tell you the class of the object. That should point you in the right direction. For objects with multiple classes, you could debug the plot function, then call that last command and see where it takes you. `debug(plot)`

Comment: In this case, the plot function called is CatDyn:::plot.CatDynData because class(lgahi) gives "CatDynData"